# Limit user to granted schema in Apache Hive (SQL Standard Based Hive Authorization)

Tags: hive

How can I limit hive user to view only granted schema in hive stand-alone defined to work with SQL Standard Based Hive Authorization?

By limiting I mean removing permission to list schemas user doesn't granted permissions to (show schemas;) and not permit describe tables from other schemas (use other_schema; describe tables);

**hive-site.xml**

```
hive.security.authorization.enabled: true
hive.server2.enable.doAs: false
hive.users.in.admin.role: hive
```

**hiveserver2-site.xml**

```
hive.security.authorization.manager:
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdHiveAuthorizerFactory
hive.security.authorization.enabled: true
hive.security.authenticator.manager:
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.SessionStateUserAuthenticator
```

**hive schemas and tables**

```
CREATE SCHEMA db_test1;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db_test1.test_table_1 (title STRING, comment_count INT)
LOCATION 's3a://bucket/hive/test1/test_table_1';

CREATE SCHEMA db_test2;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db_test2.test_table_2 (title STRING, comment_count INT)
LOCATION 's3a://bucket/hive/test2/test_table_2';
```

**grants**

```
create role test1;
create role test2;
grant select on table db_test1.test_table_1 to role test1;
grant select on table db_test2.test_table_2 to role test2;
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE db_test1 TO ROLE test1_role;
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE db_test2 TO ROLE test2_role;
grant role test1 to user test1;
grant role test2 to user test1;
```

Comment: Do you want to assign role to database instead doing it on tables?

Comment: yes, forgot to add the lines where i m granting role select permissions for scpecific schema

GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE db_test1 TO ROLE test1_role;
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE db_test2 TO ROLE test2_role;

Comment: Any errors or what is the specific question?

Comment: yes, when user is granted to specific schema he still can list other schemas, 
by running show schemas;
and list tables running describe tables on schemas he doesn't own
how can I remove these permissions ?